# Custom primary key in Django model

Tags: python, django, primary-key

Here is my model:

```
class InvitationCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

According to [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key),

> primary_key=True implies null=False and unique=True.

However this is not what I see:

```
>>> from app.models import InvitationCode
>>> c = InvitationCode(group_id=1)
>>> c.save()
>>> c.pk
''
>>> c1 = InvitationCode(group_id=1)
>>> c1.save()
>>> InvitationCode.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<InvitationCode: InvitationCode object ()>]>
```

- Why Django allowed me to have primary key as empty string?
- Why uniqueness constrain didn't work?

Comment: The uniqueness constraint *did* work. Note that despite saving two objects, the query only returned one; the second save simply overwrote the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have to call `full_clean` in order to perform validation. As [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) says -

> Note that full_clean() will not be called automatically when you call
>   your model’s save() method. You’ll need to call it manually when you
>   want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created
>   models.

Answer (score 0):

You should put value to this field. So you should build it like this:

```
c = InvitationCode(group_id=1, code=1)
```

That's the way how your model is created. It is not **autofield**.

Comment: Indeed I should, but it doesn't answer the question "why django doesn't perform validation".

Comment: I've tested it on admin site and validation works. When you save isntance with pk that is already in databav in shell - it just replaces other instance that has same pk.

Comment: In admin UI yes, but not in the shell.